# How to move displayed text upper in HTML?

Tags: html, wordpress, plugins

I have the following [site](http://idleslidegloves.com), as one can see the gif is under the subscribe box, I looked around the following code:

```
<body class="<?php echo $body_classes ? $body_classes : ''; ?>">
<div class="container" style="width: 40%; margin: 0 auto;">
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/idleslidegloves/" style="float: left;"><img src="http://idleslidegloves.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/instagram-22.png"  alt=""></a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/idleslidegloves/" style="float: right;"><img src="http://idleslidegloves.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/facebook-7-22.png" alt=""></a>
</div>
        <div class="wrap">
            <?php if (!empty($heading)) { ?><h1><?php echo stripslashes($heading); ?></h1><?php } ?>
            <?php if (!empty($text)) { ?><h2><?php echo stripslashes($text); ?></h2><?php } ?>
```

How I remove the empty space or move the whole Subscribe box upper so in lower resolutions it wont be displayed under the GIF. As seen here http://prntscr.com/9shcj8 . Noted these edits are over an existing plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit the stylesheet (or `style` tag) not the html code. Change your wrap class margin to anthoer value :

```
.wrap{
    margin:45px auto 0; //for example
}
```

Comment: I have the following wraps https://gist.github.com/highacid/56aa5aca2eb1988f1d2f in css. where should I edit?

Comment: Change the margin value in the first one.